# Laravel Route Troubleshooting

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-medialibrary

I am trying to figure out why my route is throwing a 404 error rather than providing my image.  I am using Spatie media library to serve private images.

I have the following routes web.php:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/images/{$gift}/{$uuid}', 'ImageController@show')->name('images.show');
    Route::resource('games', 'GameController');
    Route::resource('players', 'PlayerController');
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

When I do this:  `{{ route('images.show', [$gift, $gift->getFirstMedia()->uuid]) }}` in my blade, the URL is correctly generated.  However, clicking on the link results in a 404 error.

The ImageController@show function exists, and currently does nothing more than `dd('here');` so I am sure that Laravel is never even attempting to call the function.

Also, there is nothing currently in my laravel.log file.  This 404 error does not generate a log entry.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining route parameters in the URI they are just names, they are not PHP variables:

```
'/images/{$gift}/{$uuid}'
```

Should be:

```
'images/{gift}/{uuid}'
```

Comment: Thank you!!  Stupid mistakes are stupid.  =)